# How to replace a text after the pattern is found in .sh

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
data.txt file : 
Roll no : 65 
Name    : Abc
Roll no : 67 
Name    : Pqr
Roll no : 68 
Name    : Xyz
```

Now, I want to take *Roll no* as input from user and then replace the old name with new name

```
sed  -i -e 's/'$tmproll'/{'$tmpName';s/\n.*//;}' $filename
sed  -i -e 's/'$tmproll'/'$tmpName'/{N;s/\n.*//;}' $filename
```

Expected Result :

```
Enter the Roll no to modify : 65
Enter new Name for that Roll no  : Mno
Then data.txt file : 
Roll no : 65 
Name    : Mno
Roll no : 67 
Name    : Pqr
Roll no : 68 
Name    : Xyz
```

My actual output

```
Enter the Roll no to modify : 65
Enter new Name for that Roll no  : Mno
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Can you show us your complete code please?

Comment: Please post it as code in your post. It's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Just double-quote the `sed` expression so normal variable-expansion occurs, e.g. `sed "s/find/replace/"`

Comment: I'm new to this site and I dont know how to post as code,can you tell me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you erroneously put an `s` before the first slash. `s/regex/replacement/` replaces matches of `regex` with the text `replacement`, whereas just `/regex/` is an address expression which selects lines which match `regex`.

You also put the replacement in a weird place, but your second attempt looks fixable with fairly minor changes. Try

```
sed  -i -e '/'"$tmproll"'/{N;s/\n.*/\nName: '"$tmpName"'/;}' "$filename"
```

Notice also the quoting fixes; see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (the quoting could actually be simplified quite a bit by switching to double quotes altogether).

In more detail, a `sed` script consists of a sequence of *address* *command* pairs. The *address* is optional; in its absence, the *command* is applied to every input line. This script contains the commands `N` (fetch the next input line, so that the pattern space contains both the original line and the following one, separated by a newline character) and `s/regex/replacement/` to replace the text after the newline character (i.e. the new line we fetched with `N`) with new text. The commands are inside braces to say they all should be applied if the address expression matched.

Using `sed` for any non-trivial logic tends to produce write-only scripts; this would arguably be easier to write and understand in Awk.

```
awk -v no="$tmproll" -v name="$tmpName" '/Roll no / && $4 == no { replace=1 }
    /Name / && replace { $3=name }1' "$filename"
```

You will need to write the result to a temporary file and then rename it if you don't have GNU Awk, which has an `inplace` facility similar to `sed -i`.

Comment: Your ans works perfectly well. But can you explain **{N;s/\n.*/\nName: '"$tmpName"'/;}**

Comment: I added a simple explanation, but you really should seek a general `sed` introduction if you want to understand it properly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using sed for in-place editing, you might consider `ed`, of all things (It's actually quite useful for simple editing of files in a script).

Demonstration script:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmproll=65
tmpname=Mno

ed -s data.txt <<EOF
/^Roll no[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*${tmproll}$/+1 s/:.*/: ${tmpname}/
w
EOF
```

It looks for a line matching the desired roll number (The leading `/regex/`), and on the line after it (`+1`), replaces everything after the colon with the new name (The `s///`). Then it saves the file (`w`).

Example:

```
$ cat data.txt
Roll no : 65 
Name    : Abc
Roll no : 67 
Name    : Pqr
Roll no : 68 
Name    : Xyz
$ sh example.sh
$ cat data.txt
Roll no : 65 
Name    : Mno
Roll no : 67 
Name    : Pqr
Roll no : 68 
Name    : Xyz
```

Comment: OK, will let you know

Comment: I tried your code @shawn but whenever i copied it and paste it into vs code it gave me error

Comment: @ShubhamPawar Your *editor* is giving an error when you try pasting into it?

Comment: 'modify.sh: line 36: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF/^Roll')
modify.sh: line 6: ed: command not found
'

Comment: @ShubhamPawar Those are errors from `/bin/sh`, nothing to do with vscode or any other editor. You left out some lines from the above script for the first one, and the second one is self-explanatory but surprising. ed is in POSIX... what unixish OS doesn't include it as part of a base installation?

Comment: I'm actual not working not unix/linux based os. I'm working on windows with *GIT Bash*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it the right way to do this but I have come up with a solution.
So first we'll try to find the line number of the ***Roll no*** in the file,then wel'll increment it by one,since our ***Name*** comes after ***Roll no***. Then we'll replace that line with the desired ***Name*** that we want.
Here's the code for it :

```
Data.txt before modification 
Roll no : 65 
Name    : ABC
Roll no : 66 
Name    : DEF
Roll no : 67 
Name    : MNO

#CODE STARTS FROM HERE

echo -n "Enter the Roll no to modify : " 
read tmproll 
if grep -q $tmproll "$filename"; then 
lineno=$(sed  -n -e '/'$tmproll'/=' $filename)
lineno=$((lineno+1));
echo -n "Enter the new Name : "
read tmpName
sed -i -e "$lineno c\Name    : $tmpName" $filename
fi 

#CODE ENDS HERE

Data.txt after this code 
Roll no : 65 
Name    : ABC
Roll no : 66 
Name    : DEF
Roll no : 67 
Name    : PQR
```

Comment: I know that this is not the standard method,but this does actually work for me.. ;)